# Correct syntax of the variable "Set" for program execution and error log

Tags: batch-file, variables, cmd, batch-processing

I am creating unattended batch file programs but have problems with the correct detection of the variable to run properly.

```
SET installjava=JAVA\jre-8u111-windows-i586.exe /s AUTO_UPDATE=0 WEB_ANALYTICS=0 REBOOT=0 SPONSORS=0 REMOVEOUTOFDATEJRES=1 || ECHO "%time% Java install did not complete." >> "%Temp%\ERROR.TXT"
```

What syntax should be used to properly run the installation file and the error log about the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
SET "installjava=JAVA\jre-8u111-windows-i586.exe /s AUTO_UPDATE=0 WEB_ANALYTICS=0 REBOOT=0 SPONSORS=0 REMOVEOUTOFDATEJRES=1 || ECHO %time% Java install did not complete.>> "%Temp%\ERROR.TXT""
```

The environment variable `installjava` must be referenced with immediate expansion, i.e. with `%installjava%` to really work as command line for execution.

See the answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) why using the syntax `set "variable=value"` which is necessary here because of the operators `||` and `>>` to be interpreted as literal characters on assigning the command line to the environment variable.

The **ECHO** is without double quotes as these double quotes would be also written into the error log file. Also there is no space left of redirection operator `>>` to get the error message written into the error log file without a trailing space character.